# Make a certain image unaffected by img css

Tags: css, styles

I have this CSS on my page.

```
img {
  opacity:0.4;
  filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}

img:hover {
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

I want to have a few images that aren't affected by this `opacity`. How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Add a class to it to make it more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to give it a **unique** ID and target it separately:

```css
img#theID { 
// CSS for that particular image here
}
```

Comment: Definitely this method, avoid inline styles if possible.

Answer (score 0):

## Method 1

The most popular method to accomplish something like this suggests the usage of specificity. Basically, the more specific the selector is, the higher precedence. Consider this markup

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="blahblah.jpg" />
    <div class="wrap">
      <img src="blahblahblah.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
<section>
<img>
<img>
```

If you use

```
img {
  /* Styles */
}
```

Those styles will be applied to all. But if you used something like this

```
section .container .wrap img {
  /* Different Styles */
}
```

Those styles will take precedence for that image, because CSS likes the most specific answer you can give.

## Method 2

In addition to this answer given by [user125697](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15627008/1470950), which suggests using id's as such

```
/* img#ID - ID can be whatever you want*/
img#hover {
  opacity:1;
  filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

And you would impliment it as such

```
<img id="hover" src="blahblah.jpg" />
```

Chris Coyier has published a pen about [this](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lzjqh). To test the results, just remove one of the classes from the box, and you will see that it changes colors. So basically classes are always overridden by IDs

## Method 3

### Not Encouraged

The final method I know of is to use `!important`, which overrides every style on the page. No matter what. This is highly disapproved of, because it can create a lot of problems down the road.